# React native border radius to inside

Tags: react-native

I would like to make view as image. Border radius to inside. How can i do this on react native. black area is transparent and ignore orange square

[image]

Comment: Have you actually tried something?

Comment: I think , I can put a circle there and the circle color can be same as background color.

Answer (score 4):

this is how I hacked it:
[screen shoot of the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/66Hyu.png)

```
import React from 'react';
import {SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, View, Text} from 'react-native';

const App: () => React$Node = () => {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.safeView}>
      <View style={styles.BoX}>
        <View style={styles.innerBox}>
          <Text>Put ur image here</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.topLeft} />
        <View style={styles.topRight} />
        <View style={styles.bottomLeft} />
        <View style={styles.bottomRight} />
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  safeView: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  BoX: {
    width: 300,
    height: 300,
    position: 'relative',
    overflow: 'hidden',
    alignSelf: 'center',
  },
  innerBox: {
    flex: 1,
    borderColor: 'orange',
    borderWidth: 2,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  topLeft: {
    width: 20,
    height: 20,
    borderRadius: 10,
    left: -10,
    top: -10,
    borderColor: 'orange',
    borderWidth: 2,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    position: 'absolute',
  },
  topRight: {
    width: 20,
    height: 20,
    borderRadius: 10,
    right: -10,
    top: -10,
    borderColor: 'orange',
    borderWidth: 2,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    position: 'absolute',
  },
  bottomLeft: {
    width: 20,
    height: 20,
    borderRadius: 10,
    left: -10,
    bottom: -10,
    borderColor: 'orange',
    borderWidth: 2,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    position: 'absolute',
  },
  bottomRight: {
    width: 20,
    height: 20,
    borderRadius: 10,
    right: -10,
    bottom: -10,
    borderColor: 'orange',
    borderWidth: 2,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    position: 'absolute',
  },
});

export default App;
```